# Автоформатирование однострочных методов в intelij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings, intellisense

Итак, на так давно перешел с eclipse на Intellij idea, которая мне очень понравилась. Но есть одна вещь, которая просто сводит меня с ума. Все методы с реализацией короче чем в 2 строки, он форматирует в одну строку вот таким образом.

`public void method(Object parameter) { doSomething(parameter) }`

При этом, при клике на метод, он сам форматируется в нормальный вид до перезапуска.

Comment: В настройках, разумеется, смотрел. Разумеется, гуглил.

Comment: Он форматирует только для показа в редакторе, в исходных файлах ничего не меняется. Вы хотите отключить опцию?

Comment: Да, было бы здорово, но я не нашел где это сделать, все настройки облазил.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995083/intellij-collapsing-single-line-methods

Comment: Примного благодарен

Comment: вообще советую использовать Ctrl + Shift + A, поиск очень умный, достаточно было набрать Collapse on

Answer (score 5):

теперь указанная галочка находится в разделе Java[image: скриншот]